# how to know which element has another element lost focus to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('.xys').live('blur', function() {
});
```

Say that I have a `input textfield` with `class xyz`. This function successfully tells me that the element has lost focus. But how do I get to know that which element has it lost focus to?

Explaining further if say that I click somewhere else or press `tab` to move to another text field how can I know where has it gone?

Comment: use `focus()` and `blur()` to see the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `target` property of `event` object:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.xys', function(event) {
     alert('blur: ' + event.target.id)
     // or alert(event.target.localName)
});

$(document).on('focus', '.xys', function(event) {
     alert('focus: ' + event.target.id)
     // or alert(event.target.tagName)
});
```

Note that `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method.

Comment: This gives the id of xys on blur. I do not need the focus in any case

Comment: In the blur function, it gives the id of the class xys all the time not to where the focus has been shifted!

Comment: @Shivang `blur` gives you the id of element that have lost the focus not the focus handler.

Comment: Ya so my question is to get the id of the focus handler. Sorry if the question was ambiguous

Comment: @Shivang I have included both focus and blur in the answer, one of them gives you the details of the element that have lost the focus an the other one gives the details of the element that is in the focus. there is no other event.